# Associate a CancellationToken with an async method's Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

Question: Is there a way to associate a `CancellationToken` with the `Task` returned from an `async` method?

Generally, a `Task` will end up in the `Canceled` state if an `OperationCancelledException` is thrown with a `CancellationToken` matching the `Task`'s `CancellationToken`.  If they don't match, then the task goes into the `Faulted` state:

```
void WrongCancellationTokenCausesFault()
{
    var cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts2.Cancel();

    // This task will end up in the Faulted state due to the task's CancellationToken
    // not matching the thrown OperationCanceledException's token.
    var task = Task.Run(() => cts2.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), cts1.Token);  
}
```

With `async`/`await`, I haven't found a way to set the method's `Task`'s `CancellationToken` (and thus achieve the same sort of functionality).  From my testing, it seems that *any* `OperationCancelledException` will cause the `async` method to enter the Cancelled state:

```
async Task AsyncMethodWithCancellation(CancellationToken ct)
{
    // If ct is cancelled, this will cause the returned Task to be in the Cancelled state
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
    await Task.Delay(1);

    // This will cause the returned Task to be in the Cancelled state
    var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    newCts.Cancel();
    newCts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

It would be nice to have a little more control, since if a method I call from my `async` method is cancelled (and I don't expect cancellation--i.e. its not this `Task`'s `CancellationToken`), I would expect the task to enter the `Faulted` state--not the `Canceled` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the design works well for the common case: if any child operations are cancelled, then the cancellation propagates to the parent (the most common case is that the parent and child share cancellation tokens).

If you want different semantics, you can `catch` the `OperationCanceledException` in your `async` method and throw an exception that fits the semantics you need. If you want to use these semantics repeatedly, an extension method for `Task` should fit the bill.

Comment: I agree--it works well for the common case.  It's a little odd that a child `Task` (non-`async`) could end up faulted (due to an `OperationCancelledException` with the wrong token), but then that would cause the parent (`async`) Task to be in the Cancelled state.  Mostly I was just curious and worried about the bug case:  an unexpected cancellation would not cause my `async` code to fail and perhaps delay me in noticing the bug.

Comment: There are some corner cases re cancellation; e.g., if you pass an already-canceled token to `Task.Run`, you'll get a canceled task that raises `TaskCanceledException` when `await`ed, but if you cancel a token passed to `Task.Run` after the task starts, you'll get a canceled task that raises `OperationCanceledException` (*not* `TaskCanceledException`) when `await`ed. Anyway, you shouldn't have to worry about bugs because you should eventually `await` all tasks (that you care about), and any canceled task will throw `OperationCanceledException` when `await`ed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Run` method that attempts to imitate the behavior of the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method, when supplied with a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) argument. The task returned by the `Run` can only become [`Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) if the async method returns a `Canceled` task, and also the associated `CancellationToken` matches the supplied argument.

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes an async method (a method implemented with the async keyword), and
/// returns a proxy of the produced async task. In case the async task completes
/// in a Canceled state but the causative CancellationToken is not equal with the
/// cancellationToken argument, the proxy transitions to a Faulted state.
/// In all other cases, the proxy propagates the status of the async task as is.
/// </summary>
public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> asyncMethod,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return asyncMethod().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsCanceled)
        {
            TaskCanceledException tce = new(t);
            // In case the async method has been canceled by an unknown token,
            // propagate a faulted task.
            if (tce.CancellationToken != cancellationToken)
                return Task.FromException<TResult>(tce);
        }

        return t; // In any other case, propagate the task as is.
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default)
    .Unwrap();
}
```

Usage example:

```
Task<int> task = Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000, new CancellationToken(true));
    return 13;
}, new CancellationToken(false));

try { task.Wait(); } catch { }

Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
```

Output:

```
Faulted
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9vqubY).

Comment: What is the rationale behind `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`?

Comment: @KyleMcClellan the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` has the effect of executing the continuation synchronously, on the same thread where the antecedent `Task` was completed. The default behavior is to execute the continuation on the `ThreadPool`, which makes sense if the continuation does a lot of work, so that the other subscribers are not delayed. In this case the continuation does close to nothing, so offloading it to another thread would have more costs than benefits.