# How does cancellation acknowledgment work for async continuations?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

The [documentation for `Task.IsCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled?view=net-8.0#remarks) specifies that `OperationCanceledException.CancellationToken` has to match the cancellation token used to start the task in order to properly acknowledge. I'm confused about how this works within an asynchronous continuation. There appears to be some undocumented behavior that allows them to acknowledge despite not knowing their cancellation token ahead of time.

```cs
static void TestCancelSync()
{
    // Create a CTS for an already running task.
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.Cancel();

    // Attempt to acknowledge cancellation of the CT (doesn't work).
    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

static async Task TestCancelAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();

    // Create a CTS for an already running continuation.
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.Cancel();

    // Acknowledge cancellation of the CT (how is this possible?).
    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}

var syncCancelTask = Task.Run(TestCancelSync);
var asyncCancelTask = TestCancelAsync();

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(syncCancelTask, asyncCancelTask);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Prints "{ syncCanceled = False, asyncCanceled = True }"
    Console.WriteLine(
        new
        {
            syncCanceled = syncCancelTask.IsCanceled,
            asyncCanceled = asyncCancelTask.IsCanceled,
        });
}
```

I'd like to understand how this is working under the hood. When exactly is it necessary to acknowledge cancellation for a specific token? Can I trust that any tasks from an async method will have this undocumented behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The documentation for `Task.IsCanceled` specifies that `OperationCanceledException.CancellationToken` has to match the cancellation token used to start the task in order to properly acknowledge.

Indeed. The documentation of the [`Task.IsCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled) probably hasn't been updated since its introduction with the .NET Framework 4.0 (2010). It looks like it is associated with the behavior of the [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) method, which takes a ([sometimes misunderstood](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html)) `CancellationToken` as argument, and takes into account this argument when the `action` delegate fails with an `OperationCanceledException`. Asynchronous methods that are implemented with the `async` keyword do not work this way. They always complete in the `Canceled` state whenever an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown, regardless of the identity of the `CancellationToken` that caused the cancellation. In your question you are experimenting with an `async` method, so you get this behavior, which deviates from the documentation of the `Task.IsCanceled` property.

If for some reason you want the `Task.Factory.StartNew` behavior with your `async` methods, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257356/associate-a-cancellationtoken-with-an-async-methods-task) question for ideas.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you seem to be observing is the way Task cancellation and the OperationCanceledException work in .NET, especially in the context of async continuations.

**Task Cancellation:** In .NET, a Task can be in one of 3 final states:

- RanToCompletion
- Faulted
- Canceled

A Task is considered canceled if it acknowledges the cancellation request by throwing an OperationCanceledException that is linked to the CancellationToken that was used to request the cancellation.

**OperationCanceledException:** This includes a property **CancellationToken** that indicates which token triggered the cancellation. The task infrastructure checks if this token matches the token associated with the task's cancellation request. If they match, the task is marked as Canceled, otherwise it's marked as Faulted.

Your first scenario **TestCancelSync** does not interact with that task directly related to the **CancellationTokenSource** (CTS). The **ThrowIfCancellationRequested** method throws an **OperationCanceledException**, but since it's not thrown within the context of a task that was started with the token from **cts**, there's no task cancellation to acknowledge. Therefore, the task running this method is not marked as canceled but instead completes normally or faults because of the unhandled exception.

With your second scenario **TestCancelAsync**, the key is understanding how "await" and async continuations work. When you await something inside an async method, the compiler transforms the remainder of the method into a continuation that should run after the awaited operation completes. If an **OperationCanceledException** is thrown after an await in an async method, the task infrastructure can implicitly associate this exception with the task being awaited, even if the cancellation token is not explicitly passed to the method or task. What you're experiencing (where the async method's task is marked as canceled) happens because the **OperationCanceledException** thrown is captured and treated as cancelling the task returned by the async method. This works seamlessly because async methods are designed to handle this exception by observing it and transitioning the task into the Canceled state.

**Can you trust the behavior?** Relying on implicit behavior for task cancellation can make your code less clear and potentially introduce bugs if the logic becomes more complex. It's good practice to explicitly check for cancellation with the specific **CancellationToken** you're working with and pass the token to all async operations that support it. Doing this makes your code more readable and ensures that cancellation behaviors are explicit and predictable. While you can trust this behavior for tasks originating from async methods, for clarity, maintainability, and predictability, I advise you to handle cancellations explicitly whenever possible.

Comment: To paraphrase ChatGPT's explanation, `Can you trust AI answers?` No, which is why [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)